# how to change path of downloaded file for android in mainactivity in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, download

I have added downloading functionality and it is working fine but the downloaded file is storing in `storage/emulated/0/Application/data/file/Download` folder. But I want to change the path of download and want to download at `storage/emulated/0/Download` folder. My code is as below.

```
public void Downloaded() 
{
    CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func < IDownloadFile, string > (file = > {
        string fileName = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Url).Path.Split('/').Last();
        return Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);
    });
}
```

And if I add Static path for download then it shows error for permission as current process has `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I already provided permissions for writing.

Comment: `storage/emulated/0/Application/data/file/Download` I doubt that. Isnt it `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/Download` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the storage directory for public files on external storage as `PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

The code could get the download folder which you want.

```
var DIR = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
```

[image]